# Where to find app.js file in angular nativescript?

Tags: node.js, nativescript, angular-nativescript

I'm trying to create a nativescript app with angular and after creating the app with node I can't seem to find the app.js / server.js file
Where can I find it or do i need to create it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no app.js or server.js in an Angular Nativescript app, the projet main.ts is what you're looking for.